# ui:inputSelect inside an aura:iteration doesn't get destroyed and unrendered when collection is changed

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

This is quite a wierd one, I have a list of records which I'm rendering using an `aura:iteration`. Within that I'm rendering a field using a `ui:inputSelect` and as part of the component the user has the ability to add/remove rows i.e. items from the collection. At some point the user will save/cancel and the collection is updated. When this happens, items that have been removed from the collection disappear from the `aura:iteration`, with the exception of the `ui:inputSelect` components which remain. I've put together an example component that recreates the issue. If you click the `Add` button a few times, and then click the `Reset` button you'll see the input fields don't get removed as you would expect. If you click `Check` and take a look at the output in the console you can see the collection contains entries that should have been removed, but presumably haven't because of the active binding on those inputs. If you switch the field to a `ui:inputText` it all behaves as you would expect.

*TestComponent.cmp*

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">

    <aura:attribute name="records" type="List" />

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />

    <ui:button label="Add" press="{!c.add}" />
    <ui:button label="Reset" press="{!c.reset}" />
    <ui:button label="Check" press="{!c.check}" />

    <ul>
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.records}" var="rec">
            <aura:if isTrue="{!rec.Description != ''}">
                <li>
                    <ui:inputSelect aura:id="input" label="{!rec.Name}" value="{!rec.Description}">
                        <ui:inputSelectOption label="Test" text="Test" />
                        <ui:inputSelectOption label="Other" text="Other" />
                    </ui:inputSelect>
                </li>
            </aura:if>
        </aura:iteration>
    </ul>

</aura:component>
```

*TestComponentController.js*

```
({
    init: function(component, event, helper)
    {
        helper.init(component);
    },

    add: function(component, event, helper)
    {
        helper.addRecord(component);
    },

    reset: function(component, event, helper)
    {
        helper.init(component);
    },

    check: function(component, event, helper)
    {
        helper.checkRecords(component);
    }
})
```

*TestComponentHelper.js*

```
({
    init: function(component)
    {
        component.set('v.records', [
                { Name: 'Test 1', Description: 'Test'},
                { Name: 'Test 2', Description: 'Test'},
                { Name: 'Test 3', Description: 'Test'},
                { Name: 'Test 4', Description: 'Test'},
                { Name: 'Test 5', Description: 'Test'},
            ]);
    },

    addRecord: function(component)
    {
        var records = component.get('v.records');

        records.push({ Name: 'New Record', Description: 'New Record'});

        component.set('v.records', records);
    },

    checkRecords: function(component)
    {
        console.log(component.find('input'));
        console.log(component.get('v.records'));
    }
})
```

Comment: It looks like the component constructor and array is not getting  destroyed completely. for instance when you reset , it looks like only the Name property is getting destroyed and not the description and that is why the picklists are being  shown ,and it is partly because the Description is bound to your ui:select value  as well, when you remove this binding , the component seems to work as expected. I suspect we are running into some kind of issue with aura:iteration component.

Comment: @Sumuga it does appear to be related to the binding. One potential workaround is to remove the binding and update the value using an event handler. It's strange that only inputSelect behaves this way, binding to an inputText seems to work as expected.

Comment: Right, I am curious about the same, not sure why a two way binding attribute is causing trouble with array manipulation. Maybe you can try emptying the array before setting the value using doInit controller but i doubt it would work.

Answer (score 0):

As was described by Sumuga, the problem lies in your setting of the value in your ui:inputSelect component.  By setting the value of your inputSelect and binding it to your child component's attribute, you've permanently created a valueProvider object[api version < 40] or Proxy object [api version >= 40]. If you created your inputSelect and inputSelectOptions via Aura.createComponents, in similar fashion, but did not clearReference AND destroy the record values, you'd end up with the same issue.

Comment: Is this intended behaviour? If so, why do other input components behave differently?

Comment: Try using aura:renderIf it rerender when value changes